# Windows 10 update - kaspersky internet security installation

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender, kaspersky

I just got windows 10 update. This update seems to have removed my kaspersky internet security installation. Am I good to install it back as I am unable to remove windows defender?

Comment: Windows Defender is a Windows built-in software like Internet Explorer, you can't uninstall those, but installing any other antivirus software disables Windows Defender.

Comment: **CAUTION!!!** If Windows remove your `KIS` installation it was very likely because the version you had installed IS NOT compatible with Windows 10  If you proceed to install it, and that is the case, there is a **REALLY** good chance Windows will fail to boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of KIS was not compatible with win10. Get the mostrecent version from kaspersky.ru or kaspersky.com, it has win10 support.

PS: Windows defender will be automatically disabled after installing KIS.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 10 compatible version (UK only) is 16.0.0.614.
It works, but also generates some problems in other Windows 10 functions. 
E.g. the pin/unpin action on the Start menu is disabled. After uninstalling Kaspersky Internet Security 16.0.0.614 is is back again.
Please note to remove Kaspersky Internet Security 14 or 15 BeFORE updating to Windows 10.